# Will I become seeder, if I seed only few files in the torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent

I downloaded a [`.torrent` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file), I opened it, and 5 files were present in that torrent file. I started downloading only 3 files and after they completed downloading I started seeding those 3 files; the remaining 2 files I skipped while downloading.

So will I become seeder, if I seed only a few files in the `.torrent` file?

Answer (score 5):

You'll become a [partial seed](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0021.html):

> The purpose of this extension is to allow further optimizations of
>   bittorrent swarms when peers are partial seeds. **A partial seed is a
>   peer that is incomplete without downloading anything more.** This
>   happens for multi file torrents where users only download some of the
>   files.

This type of seeding should be supported by most of the bittorrent clients\trackers. For example, Transmission torrent client [implemented support for this feature](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/1379) 6 years ago.This is also true for uTorrent (quote from the previous link):

> uTorrent is definitely using this now

Note, that not all private bittorrent trackers take into account a partial seeding when calculating UL\DL ratio (and sometimes it's explicitly disallowed). This is usually stated in the rules of a tracker.